# ALT + TAB shows two lists

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, application-switcher

Why there are two lists stacked onto each other when I'm using `ALT` + `TAB`?

This problem was on Ubuntu 16.04 and still persists after upgrade to 18.04?

[image]
*Sorry for poor quality, had to take the photo with phone as you can't make a screenshot while `ALT` key is pressed.*

Comment: I think you enabled 2 different ALT+TAB managers. 

If you're using Gnome Shell, check under extensions which ones you enabled

Comment: The images underneath are the normal Ubuntu Unity `Alt`+`Tab` Window switcher.

Comment: @AndreaOlivato, I have Gnome Shell Extensions installed, and when I go to https://extensions.gnome.org/ it says `Unable to locate GNOME Shell settings or version. Make sure it is installed and running.` Where can I see list of the enabled extensions?

Comment: @AndreaOlivato never mind and thanks, I found the answer on duplicate question.